# My IF can run without errors but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, browser, mocha.js, cypress

I'm having trouble trying to create an IF Scenario in my cypress.
What I'm trying to do right now is to change the DurationMinutes of my website's timesheet if the DurationHours is below the specific number. However the website I'm working on is wonky, unable to type numbers and instead only works by pressing the up arrow key to change the DurationMinutes.

```js
cy.get('[ng-model="item.durationMinutes"]').each(($el, index) => 
        {
            let hours = cy.get('[ng-model="item.durationHours"]')
            let n = hours.toString()
            cy.get('[ng-model="item.durationMinutes"]').then(($hours) => 
            {
                if(n <= 10)
                {
                cy.get('[ng-model="item.durationMinutes"]')
                .click().type('{uparrow}',{multiple:true, force: true})
                }
            })
        });
```

Above is the code I've made to do the IF scenario. Although it runs in my program, it doesn't change the DurationMinutes within the specified conditions. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the field is not of type `input`so `type` shouldn't work.

Replace

```js
.type('{uparrow}',{multiple:true, force: true})
```

with

```js
.trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 38, which: 38 })
```

to simulate pressing the up arrow